# How to make Automapper ignore records based on a value of a field

Tags: automapper-6

Hi I am trying to use Automapper 6 and want to ignore records based on specific value in a field. I wish there was a way to skip records like so:

```
             CreateMap<CsfbFile, Common.Entities.FuturesExtract>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.Skip(source => source.Ccy == "BASE CURRENCY GRAND TOTAL"))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.OptionValue, m => m.ResolveUsing(s => s.OptionsLmv + s.OptionsSmv));
```

Is there a way to do this ?
Thanks

Comment: http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Conditional-mapping.html

Comment: I am not sure if this is the answer to what I asked. It is not that I am not looking to map a specific property - I am looking to ignore the whole row(object)

Comment: You can use ForAllMembers, but maybe it's easier to simply not call map at all in that case.